# Set disance between two div (two class ) same

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="div-0"></div>
<div class="div-1">
   <button-class="test-button">test1</button>
   <button-class="test-button">test2</button>
   <button-class="test-button">test3</button>

</div>
<div class="div-2"> 
   <button-class="test-button">test4</button>
   <button-class="test-button">test5</button>
   <button-class="test-button">test6</button>

</div>
<div class="div-3"></div>
```

i know how to calculate the distnce between two div .

var `disnace_new=$('.div-1').offset().top - $('.div-2').offset().top;`

For some events i will be increase the margin-top property  .example

```
$(".test-button").on("click",function(){

     $(".div-2").css("margin-top","new-value");
       continue.......

});
```

Here i cannot get new-value , also i can't acess new-value . In this situation i want to make distance between two div is -10

How it is possible.

That is `$('.div-1').offset().top - $('.div-2').offset().top`  is set to **-10**

```
$('.div-1').offset().top - $('.div-1').offset().top =-10;
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this :

```js
var distance_new = $('.div-1').offset().top - $('.div-2').offset().top;
console.log(distance_new);

$(".test-button").on("click",function(){

     $(".div-2").css("margin-top",distance_new+$('.div-1').outerHeight()+"px");
     console.log($('.div-1').offset().top - $('.div-2').offset().top);
})
```

```css
* {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.div-1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.div-2 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.space {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-0"></div>
<div class="div-1">
  <button class="test-button">test1</button>
  <button class="test-button">test2</button>
  <button class="test-button">test3</button>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="div-2">
  <button class="test-button">test4</button>
  <button class="test-button">test5</button>
  <button class="test-button">test6</button>
</div>
<div class="div-3"></div>
```